# Get the next start position of an audio when using ConcatenatingAudioSource

Tags: flutter, audio, just-audio

This is regarding using the [Just Audio](https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/issues/174) flutter package.

When using ConcatenatingAudioSource I want to be able to have one seek bar where the audio plays continuously without giving me a position of 0 when the next audio starts.

For example, when using the positionStream, when the first audio which was 30 seconds ends, I want the next audio about to play to start at position `Duration(seconds: 31)` and so on so I can create one seek bar that shows total duration of 60 seconds for example (30 second 1st audio, 30 seconds 2nd audio).

Has anyone been able to do this or know how to achieve this? I was following the example in https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio/example and read a bit about it here: https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/issues/174

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom stream that periodically emits `_player.position` but adds the elapsed duration of the previous tracks onto the total. So if each item is 30 seconds, and you're 12 seconds into the 3rd item, you want the calculation to be 30 + 30 + 12. Maybe something like this:

```dart
    Stream.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 20), (i) {
      return _player.position +
          (_player.sequence!.isEmpty
              ? Duration.zero
              : _player.sequence!
                  .sublist(0, _player.currentIndex)
                  .map((item) => item.duration!)
                  .reduce((d1, d2) => d1 + d2));
    })
```

Now this assumes that each of the past items has a known duration, which will only be true if the player has already passed through each one and it is loaded. If you seek straight to item 5 without first loading the previous items, their durations will be unknown and you won't be able to compute the total duration + position.

Note also that the above code emits position changes at a constant rate of once every 20 milliseconds. The original `positionStream` dynamically adjusts the rate for efficiency, so if you would like to also do that, you might want to look at the original source code of `positionStream` and adapt those parts.